# ImageButton in GridView TemplateField wont show AJAX Popup Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, modalpopupextender

I have a page that displays a `GridView` containing an `ImageButton TemplateField`. My goal is to display an AJAX modal popup when one of those buttons are clicked, along with displaying the row where the button is pressed. The problem is that when I click on a button, it does not show the modal popup. I tried to use this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb907626(v=vs.100).aspx) and read several articles on this site about this issue but to no avail. How to properly fire the button event and show the popup?

Here is the snippet for the gridview:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            Width="505px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemDesc" 
                    SortExpression="ItemDesc" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-Height="100px">
    <ItemStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" SortExpression="Price" 
                    ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-Height="100px">

    <ItemStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>

              <asp:TemplateField>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="200px" 
                        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' Width="200px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandName="atc"         ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/img/shop/addtocart.png" 
                            Text="Add to Cart" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)     Container).RowIndex %>"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ControlStyle Height="30px" Width="105px" />
                    <ItemStyle Width="105px" />
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
...
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="HiddenField1" PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBg" CancelControlID="btnClose">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="500" Height="500" Visible="False" 
    style="background-color:#6f95f4; color:#000000;">
    <div class="style1">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
        <table style="width: 90%; height: 71px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Item Name</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblItemName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Price</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Quantity</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Type="Number" Min="1"     MaxLength="100" 
                        Width="75px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Total Price</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddToCart" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" 
            onclick="btnAddToCart_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" onclick="btnClose_Click" Text="Close" 
            Width="199px" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

And here's my code for the event:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("atc"))
        {
            ModalPopupExtender1.Show();

            //// Retrieve the row index stored in the 
            //// CommandArgument property.
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            //// Retrieve the row that contains the button 
            //// from the Rows collection.
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
            lblItemName.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
            lblPrice.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;

            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + row.Cells[0].Text + "\n" + row.Cells[1].Text +     "');</script>");

            //// Add code here to add the item to the shopping cart.
        }

    }
```

EDIT: Added the panel code.

Comment: I forgot to include in the code. Added just now.

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint inside `GridView1_RowCommand` method and see if it's hit when you click the image button?

Comment: @SageTheGreat I Posted answer try that

Comment: @ekad Tried that, including nesting both `GridView` and extender at the update panel but throws me an exception that says An extender can't be in a different `UpdatePanel` than the control it extends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:
100% working and Tested

1. Use `onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"` for GridView
2. Use `display:none` for Your Panel instead of `Visible="false"`
3. I Commented your alert(in rowbound) it contains js error

   ```
           <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="505px"
           onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
               >
               <Columns>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemDesc" SortExpression="ItemDesc" ItemStyle-Width="100px"
                       ItemStyle-Height="100px">
                       <ItemStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
                   </asp:BoundField>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" SortExpression="Price" ItemStyle-Width="100px"
                       ItemStyle-Height="100px">
                       <ItemStyle Height="100px" Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
                   </asp:BoundField>
                   <asp:TemplateField>
                       <EditItemTemplate>
                           <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                       </EditItemTemplate>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>'
                               Width="200px" />
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandName="atc" 
                           CausesValidation="false"
                               Text="Add to Cart" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)     Container).RowIndex %>" />


                       </ItemTemplate>
                       <ControlStyle Height="30px" Width="105px" />
                       <ItemStyle Width="105px" />
                   </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
           </asp:GridView>
       </div>
       <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Panel1" 
       PopupControlID="Panel1" OnOkScript="okClick();" 
       OnCancelScript="cancelClick();" 
        OkControlID="btnAddToCart"   CancelControlID="btnClose">
   </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>


   <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

       <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="500" Height="500" 
       style="background-color:#6f95f4; color:#000000;display:none">
       <div class="style1">
       <br />
       <br />
       <br />
       <br />
       <br />
           <table style="width: 90%; height: 71px;">
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       Item Name</td>
                   <td>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblItemName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       Price</td>
                   <td>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td colspan="2">
                       &nbsp;</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       Quantity</td>
                   <td>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Type="Number" Min="1"     MaxLength="100" 
                           Width="75px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       Total Price</td>
                   <td>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblTotalPrice" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
           <br />
           <br />
                       <asp:Button ID="btnAddToCart" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" 
               onclick="btnAddToCart_Click" />
           <br />
           <br />

           <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" onclick="btnClose_Click" Text="Close" 
               Width="199px" />
       </div>
   </asp:Panel>








     protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
               {
       if (e.CommandName.Equals("atc"))
       {
       ModalPopupExtender1.Show();

       int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

           GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];


          ImageButton ImageButton1=(ImageButton)row.FindControl("ImageButton1");



              // Response.Write("<script>alert('" + row.Cells[0].Text + "\n" + row.Cells[1].Text + "');</script>");  comment this 


           }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set `OnRowCommand` property of the `GridView`, so `GridView1_RowCommand` method won't be fired when you click the image button. Here's how you do it

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Width="505px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Now the event fires, but even if the values are correct, it dos not show the popup and just posts back the page. Seems weird.

Comment: Try to put `<asp:scriptmanager>` tag at the beginning of `<form>` tag, and also put `ModalPopupExtender1` inside `<asp:UpdatePanel>`.

Comment: Gives me an exception, I'll just leave it here first and try another way.